# Why my 'Link' tags doesn't navigate and only change my page address?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When I click over `Home` and `New Blog`, my page address changes but It doesn't show relevant pages. While if I change the `Link` tag to `a` tag it does navigate fine. What's the problem with my `Link` tags?

I think anything is correct. It is a link to my project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-franklin-8n9mui?file=/src/Navbar.js

I use this for local server: `npx json-server --watch data/db.json --port 8000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in react-router-dom, after updating to version 5.3.3 it starts working.

Update:

Here is the issue and fix:

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7870

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/pull/8831

The problem is that react-router 5 was not compatible with the React 18 StrictMode `<React.StrictMode>`. This issue was fixed in version 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you change the **Link** into **a** it works because the **a** makes a hard reload for the entire page. that leads to reloading the application. that's why we use it when building forms. e.preventDefault(). to not reload the page. what **Link** do for you here. that it doesn't reload the page for you. your problem here. that you needed to not include the **Router** tag into your route file. instead, make it in the index.js file. to be used globally within your app. I fixed it for you. that's the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-cloud-gp0r58?file=/src/index.js).

New Update:

The problem is that react-router-dom v5 is in conflict with react v18.0.0. you might need to update the react-router-dom and try it.

Comment: Also, your **Router Tag** in the index.js file will be responsible to reload the application and find the matched routes inside the app.js file. then it will show to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, it fixed my problem in this case. But I want to know why it doesn't work if the Router to stay in my route file? Since it's based on Net Ninja's tutorial on youtube and there it's to this form.

Comment: I think because your app.js file has the routes for your application and when it shows the home page because also uses **exact** with your routes. after that when you try to navigate to **/Create** your app.js is not rendering so it keeps the **Home page** appearing. by adding the **Router** in index.js it helps us to re-render the **app file** based on your routes. I don't think also it's mandatory to add the **Router** within your **Routes file** you can use it from anywhere.

Comment: Please see this if is possible(here it works fine): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO-pSysGItQ&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gZD-Tvwfod2gaISzfRiP9d&index=23

Comment: I checked the video. there're some others who had this issue also. you can check the comments in the video. the problem is that react-router-dom v5 is in conflict with react v18.0.0. so I might think you can use the latest version of react-router-dom. and try for it. I updated my answer as well

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for your time. I updated it to 5.3.3 and it works:) as @davidjesch said.